# How do I map CSV header to propertyname at runtime with ChoETL

Tags: c#, choetl

Using choETL I found that I can map csv position to property name like this

```
        public class Emp
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Other{ get; set; }


            public string MyId { get; set; }
        }

        [Test]
        public void TestMapping()
        {
            ChoCSVRecordConfiguration config = new ChoCSVRecordConfiguration();
            config.CSVRecordFieldConfigurations.Add(new ChoCSVRecordFieldConfiguration("MyId", 1));
            config.CSVRecordFieldConfigurations.Add(new ChoCSVRecordFieldConfiguration("Name", 2));
            config.CSVRecordFieldConfigurations.Add(new ChoCSVRecordFieldConfiguration("Other", 3));
            config.WithFirstLineHeader(true);

            string csv = @"Id, Name, 
1, Tom, NY
2, Mark, NJ
3, Lou, FL
4, Smith, PA
5, Raj, DC
";

            using (var p = ChoCSVReader<Emp>.LoadText(csv, Encoding.ASCII,config)
//                .WithFirstLineHeader(true)
            )
            {
                Console.WriteLine(p.ToList().DumpAsJson());
            }

        }
```

However what I really want is to be able to map at runtime. Using the following pseudo code:

```
    config.CSVRecordFieldConfigurations.Add(new ChoCSVRecordFieldConfiguration("MyId", "Id"));
    config.CSVRecordFieldConfigurations.Add(new ChoCSVRecordFieldConfiguration("Name", "Name"));
    config.CSVRecordFieldConfigurations.Add(new ChoCSVRecordFieldConfiguration("Other", "City"));


    string csv1 = @"Id, Name, City
1, Tom, NY
2, Mark, NJ
3, Lou, FL
4, Smith, PA
5, Raj, DC
";

    string csv2 = @"Name, Id, City
Tom, 1, NY
Mark, 2, NJ
Lou, 3, FL
Smith, 4, PA
Raj, 5, DC
";
```

So I can use the same configuration for both csv file. They are almost identical except that the position has been swapped.
Is this possible with choETL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**: This is how you can setup the configuration to meet your requirement

```
ChoCSVRecordConfiguration config = new ChoCSVRecordConfiguration();
config.CSVRecordFieldConfigurations.Add(new ChoCSVRecordFieldConfiguration("MyId", 0) { FieldName = "Id" });
config.CSVRecordFieldConfigurations.Add(new ChoCSVRecordFieldConfiguration("Name", 0) { FieldName = "Name" });
config.CSVRecordFieldConfigurations.Add(new ChoCSVRecordFieldConfiguration("Other", 0) { FieldName = "City" });
config.WithFirstLineHeader(false);
```

Hope this helps.

---

Yes, it is possible and you started your code correctly. After reviewing your sample code, noticed that you input CSV is missing 3rd field name `City`. This may be caused the parser to fail.

Here is the working sample.

```
public class Emp
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Other { get; set; }


    public string MyId { get; set; }
}

public static void TestMapping()
{
    ChoCSVRecordConfiguration config = new ChoCSVRecordConfiguration();
    config.CSVRecordFieldConfigurations.Add(new ChoCSVRecordFieldConfiguration("MyId", 1));
    config.CSVRecordFieldConfigurations.Add(new ChoCSVRecordFieldConfiguration("Name", 2));
    config.CSVRecordFieldConfigurations.Add(new ChoCSVRecordFieldConfiguration("Other", 3));
    config.WithFirstLineHeader(true);

    string csv = @"Id, Name, City
1, Tom, NY
2, Mark, NJ
3, Lou, FL
4, Smith, PA
5, Raj, DC
";

    using (var p = ChoCSVReader<Emp>.LoadText(csv, Encoding.ASCII, config))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(p.ToList().Dump());
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[Count: 5]
-- CoinCount.Program+Emp State --
        Name: Tom
        Other: NY
        MyId: 1


-- CoinCount.Program+Emp State --
        Name: Mark
        Other: NJ
        MyId: 2


-- CoinCount.Program+Emp State --
        Name: Lou
        Other: FL
        MyId: 3


-- CoinCount.Program+Emp State --
        Name: Smith
        Other: PA
        MyId: 4


-- CoinCount.Program+Emp State --
        Name: Raj
        Other: DC
        MyId: 5
```

Here is another way, to completely manage the CSV parsing with just with POCO class

```
[ChoCSVFileHeader(IgnoreHeader = true)]
public class Emp
{
    [ChoCSVRecordField(2)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [ChoCSVRecordField(3)]
    public string Other { get; set; }
    [ChoCSVRecordField(1)]
    public string MyId { get; set; }
}

public static void TestMapping()
{
    string csv = @"Id, Name, City
1, Tom, NY
2, Mark, NJ
3, Lou, FL
4, Smith, PA
5, Raj, DC
";

    using (var p = ChoCSVReader<Emp>.LoadText(csv))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(p.ToList().Dump());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for the code. I must say this is one of the best library that I have used. I love the ease of configuration. I believe that you misunderstood my question hence I'll edit it now to make it easier to understand.

Comment: Wow that work! So the trick is to use 0 for the position and WithFirstLineHeader(false). Should we make that position optional or is this such a rare use case that you want to discourage it?

Comment: Yes, I'm making this change. Will be available on next release.